# There is a problem with the delete function of the react component implemented through the map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, swr

I am developing using react.
It is in the process of fetching the information contained in the db and displaying it on the web page through the map method.
If you delete one piece of information using onclick or the onClose method provided by antd, the info is also deleted from the db.
in the db, the function worked successfully. but the information at the bottom is deleted, not the deleted information in the web page.
If I refresh website, it is displayed normally, but I don't want to use the window reload function.
I wonder why this is happening and what is the solution.
thank you!

AlertPage

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";
import AlertComponent from "./Sections/AlertComponent";

const fetcher = async (url) =>
  await axios.get(url).then((response) => JSON.parse(response.data.alerts));

function AlertPage() {
  const { data = [], error } = useSWR("/api/streaming/getAlerts", fetcher, {
    refreshInterval: 1000,
  });

  const onClose = (data) => {
    axios.post(`/api/streaming/removeAlerts/${data._id.$oid}`).then(() => {
      console.log(`${data._id.$oid} deleted`);
    });
  };

  const renderAlerts = data.map((alert, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <AlertComponent alert={alert} index={index} onClose={onClose} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (data === []) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return <div>{renderAlerts}</div>;
}

export default AlertPage;
```

AlertComponent

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert } from "antd";
import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";

function AlertComponent(props) {
  const [alert, setalert] = useState(props.alert);
  const [index, setindex] = useState(props.index);

  return (
    <div
      className="alert"
      key={index}
      style={{ display: "flex" }}
      onClick={() => {
        props.onClose(alert);
      }}
    >
      <Alert
        message={`${alert.data.timestamp.$date.substr(0, 19)}`}
        description={
          <Marquee pauseOnHover speed={40} gradient={false}>
            {`<${alert.data.location}> <${alert.data.name}> <${alert.data.contents}> detected`}
          </Marquee>
        }
        banner
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AlertComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening due the local cache maintained by `swr` and since you're not refetching the data after the deletion the changes are not reflected in the DOM.

One options is to trigger a manual refetch to retrieve the most up-to-date data. We could achieve that by changing the following lines:

```
const { data = [], error, mutate } = useSWR("/api/streaming/getAlerts", fetcher, {
 refreshInterval: 1000
});
```

...

```
 axios.post(`/api/streaming/removeAlerts/${data._id.$oid}`).then(() => {
  mutate("/api/streaming/getAlerts");
 });
```

another approach would be to rely on the optimistic update strategy from swr, there is an example [here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#optimistic-updates)

Comment: Thank you for answer!
Thanks to this, I was able to study more about the swr mutation.
Apparently, this issue seems to be missing the last element in the deletion process because the key is just given as an index in the map method.
I solved it by replacing the key with a unique id value.